# My form isn't submitting

Tags: php, mysql

after I have filled out the necessary things, the form still wouldn't submit (or redirect to "voted.php" I have created to help me connect to the database). The radio buttons are clicking properly, but it isn't just redirecting.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Vote</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Please note that you only get to vote one time. Look carefully and make a wise choice.</h1> 

<form method="post" action="vote_process.php" >

<div class="section">
<strong>Matriculation Number:</strong> 
  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="16" name="Reg_Num" /><br />
</div>
<p><p></p></p>



<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3><strong>President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Presi_1" name="President_1" />President 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Presi 2" name="President_2" />President 2
  </form>
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3><strong>Vice President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="VP1" name="Vice_President_1" />Vice President 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="VP2" name="Vice_President_2" />Vice President 2
  </form>
</div>



<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3><strong>Secretary General:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="SecGen1" name="Secretary_General_1" />Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="SecGen2" name="Secretary_General_2" />Secretary General 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of Finance:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec1" name="Finance_1" />Director of Finance 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec2" name="Finance_2" />Director of Finance 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of Software:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Software1" name="Software_1" />Director of Software 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Software2" name="Software_2" />Director of Software 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Assistant Secretary General:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="AssSecGen1" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_1" />Assistant Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="AssSecGen2" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_2" />Assistant Secretary General 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of Information:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Info1" name="Info_1" />Director of Information 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Info2" name="Info_2" />Director of Information 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of Welfare:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Welfare1" name="Welfare_1" />Director of Welfare 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Welfare2" name="Welfare_2" />Director of Welfare 2
  </form>
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of Sports:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Sport1" name="Sports_1" />Director of Sport 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Sport2" name="Sports_2" />Director of Sport 2
  </form>
</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Director of protocol:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Protocol1" name="Protocol_1" />Director of Protocol 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Protocol2" name="Protocol_2" />Director of Protocol 2
  </form>
</div>



<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
  <form>
    <h3>Financial Secretary</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec1" name="Fin_Sec_1" />Financial Secretary 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec2" name="Fin_Sec_2" />Financial Secretary 2
  </form>
</div>

</div>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</body>

</html>
```

The database connector is:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "5050";
$dbname = "election";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sqli = "INSERT INTO `election`.`voted` (`Reg_Num`, `President_1`, `President_2`, `Vice_President_1`, `Vice_President_2`, `Secretary_General_1`, `Secretary_General_2`, `Finance_1`, `Finance_2`, `Software_1`, `Software_2`, `Assist_Sec_Gen_1`, `Assist_Sec_Gen_2`, `Info_1`, `Info_2`, `Welfare_1`, `Welfare_2`, `Sports_1`, `Sports_2`, `Protocol_1`, `Protocol_2`, `Fin_Sec_1`, `Fin_Sec_2`)
VALUES
('$_POST[Reg_Num]', '$_POST[President_1]', '$_POST[President_2]', '$_POST[Vice_President_1]', '$_POST[Vice_President_2]', '$_POST[Secretary_General_1]', '$_POST[Secretary_General_2]', '$_POST[Finance_1]', '$_POST[Finance_2]', '$_POST[Software_1]', '$_POST[Software_2]', '$_POST[Assist_Sec_Gen_1]', '$_POST[Assist_Sec_Gen_2]', '$_POST[Info_1]', '$_POST[Info_2]', '$_POST[Welfare_1]', '$_POST[Welfare_2]', '$_POST[Sports_1]', '$_POST[Sports_2]', '$_POST[Protocol_1]', '$_POST[Protocol_2]', '$_POST[Fin_Sec_1]', '$_POST[Fin_Sec_2]' );";

if ($conn->query($sqli) === TRUE) {
    echo "Voted Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}

?>  


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<title>Form Submitted</title>
<p></p>
<p>Thanks for Voting.</p>
<p></p>
<p>Please note that you cannot vote two times</p>
<p></p>
<a href="registration.php">Another Voter</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: remove extra <form> tags.

Comment: I am confused.. why do you have so many form tags? Also, you never close the very first form. Try removing all other form tags and close the first form after you rendered all input fields.

Answer (score 1):

our HTML code is a bit borked there, this should help fix it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Vote</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Please note that you only get to vote one time. Look carefully and make a wise choice.</h1> 

<form method="post" action="vote_process.php" >

<div class="section">
<strong>Matriculation Number:</strong> 
  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="16" name="Reg_Num" /><br />
</div>
<p><p></p></p>



<div class="section">

    <h3><strong>President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Presi_1" name="President_1" />President 1
    <input type="radio" value="Presi_2" name="President_2" />President 2

</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3><strong>Vice President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" value="VP1" name="Vice_President_1" />Vice President 1
    <input type="radio" value="VP2" name="Vice_President_2" />Vice President 2

</div>



<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3><strong>Secretary General:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" value="SecGen1" name="Secretary_General_1" />Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" value="SecGen2" name="Secretary_General_2" />Secretary General 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of Finance:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="FinSec1" name="Finance_1" />Director of Finance 1
    <input type="radio" value="FinSec2" name="Finance_2" />Director of Finance 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of Software:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Software1" name="Software_1" />Director of Software 1
    <input type="radio" value="Software2" name="Software_2" />Director of Software 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Assistant Secretary General:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="AssSecGen1" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_1" />Assistant Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" value="AssSecGen2" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_2" />Assistant Secretary General 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of Information:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Info1" name="Info_1" />Director of Information 1
    <input type="radio" value="Info2" name="Info_2" />Director of Information 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of Welfare:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Welfare1" name="Welfare_1" />Director of Welfare 1
    <input type="radio" value="Welfare2" name="Welfare_2" />Director of Welfare 2

</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of Sports:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Sport1" name="Sports_1" />Director of Sport 1
    <input type="radio" value="Sport2" name="Sports_2" />Director of Sport 2

</div>


<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Director of protocol:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="Protocol1" name="Protocol_1" />Director of Protocol 1
    <input type="radio" value="Protocol2" name="Protocol_2" />Director of Protocol 2

</div>



<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">

    <h3>Financial Secretary</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="FinSec1" name="Fin_Sec_1" />Financial Secretary 1
    <input type="radio" value="FinSec2" name="Fin_Sec_2" />Financial Secretary 2

</div>

</div>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

As you've indicated that you can only vote one time I'd recommend adding some measures to prevent the same form being submitted twice.

Also, to help you to debug the Posted Data in the PHP script, this next bit of code usually helps to check what's being posted:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>;
?>
```

You'll want to mysqli_real_escape_string and prepare your POST data also prior to insertion to help prevent MYSQL attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your form element has two name attribute... remove 1st name attribute which is name="radio_array[]"

update your insert query:

```
$sqli = "INSERT INTO `election`.`voted` (`Reg_Num`, `President_1`, `President_2`, `Vice_President_1`, `Vice_President_2`, `Secretary_General_1`, `Secretary_General_2`, `Finance_1`, `Finance_2`, `Software_1`, `Software_2`, `Assist_Sec_Gen_1`, `Assist_Sec_Gen_2`, `Info_1`, `Info_2`, `Welfare_1`, `Welfare_2`, `Sports_1`, `Sports_2`, `Protocol_1`, `Protocol_2`, `Fin_Sec_1`, `Fin_Sec_2`)
VALUES
('".$_POST['Reg_Num']."', '".$_POST["President_1"]."', '".$_POST["President_2]."', '".$_POST["Vice_President_1"]'"......";
```

like this....
Also you should take precaution for sql injection

Comment: question is form not submitting. User have no issue in insert query.

Answer (score 0):

lol, your `input type="submit"` button is OUTSIDE of the `form`..... it should be inside the `form` tag. Also make just one form instead of 100, except when you don't want to submit all input fields at once.

Remember that every form needs an submit button. Or else It will not submit anything.

[Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

```
<form method="post" action="vote_process.php" >

<div class="section">
<strong>Matriculation Number:</strong> 
  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="16" name="Reg_Num" /><br />
</div>
<p><p></p></p>

<div class="section">
    <h3><strong>President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Presi_1" name="President_1" />President 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Presi 2" name="President_2" />President 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3><strong>Vice President:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="VP1" name="Vice_President_1" />Vice President 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="VP2" name="Vice_President_2" />Vice President 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3><strong>Secretary General:</strong></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="SecGen1" name="Secretary_General_1" />Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="SecGen2" name="Secretary_General_2" />Secretary General 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of Finance:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec1" name="Finance_1" />Director of Finance 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec2" name="Finance_2" />Director of Finance 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of Software:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Software1" name="Software_1" />Director of Software 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Software2" name="Software_2" />Director of Software 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Assistant Secretary General:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="AssSecGen1" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_1" />Assistant Secretary General 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="AssSecGen2" name="Assist_Sec_Gen_2" />Assistant Secretary General 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of Information:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Info1" name="Info_1" />Director of Information 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Info2" name="Info_2" />Director of Information 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of Welfare:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Welfare1" name="Welfare_1" />Director of Welfare 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Welfare2" name="Welfare_2" />Director of Welfare 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of Sports:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Sport1" name="Sports_1" />Director of Sport 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Sport2" name="Sports_2" />Director of Sport 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Director of protocol:</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Protocol1" name="Protocol_1" />Director of Protocol 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="Protocol2" name="Protocol_2" />Director of Protocol 2
</div>

<p></p><p></p>
<div class="section">
    <h3>Financial Secretary</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec1" name="Fin_Sec_1" />Financial Secretary 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_array[]" value="FinSec2" name="Fin_Sec_2" />Financial Secretary 2
</div>

</div>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form> <-- close it here
```